# Why Firebase Analytics SDK automatically gets added when installing Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

I'm developing an iOS application in which I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging. When I'm installing the FCM SDK, in the Pod's section, the Firebase Analytics SDK automatically installed. Please anyone let me know.

Comment: Can you post your Podfile? if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Analytics is the core of Firebase and it "also integrates with a number of other Firebase features. For example, it automatically logs events that correspond to your Firebase Notifications and provides reporting on the impact of each campaign." If you don't want it, you can disable it ([here](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics))